# Entity Framework 4.0 and Stored Procedures

Tags: entity-framework-4

Are there any examples/articles on how to use the Entity Framework 4.0 Code First model (no edmx or xml configuration anywhere!!!) that interacts with stored procedures? Another aspect to my requirements is I am using a Repository pattern that uses an IRepository interface to abstract the actual data store (memory, database, xml, etc).  Thus, I suppose it would be a hack to expose the ObjectContext so that I can call ExecuteFunction(...) on the ObjectContext instance since the caller of IRepository can never assume it is hitting a database.  I was hoping to specify all stored procedure mapping logic in my mapping class for the entity.  The mapping class is a subclass of EntityConfiguration. Is the 4.0 CTP mature enough for this yet?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late now, but here is something worthwhile looking into: [Entity Framework CTP5 - How to Call Stored Procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789788/entity-framework-ctp5-how-to-call-stored-procedure) and [Using stored procedures with Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001441/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-4-code-first-ctp5).  Did you manage with this?