# Entity Framework CTP5 - How to Call Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5

This may be a simple answer, but i can't see how to execute a stored procedure with EF CTP5.

In Entity Framework 4.0, we did this:

`ExecuteFunction("ContainerName.StoredProcName", new ObjectParameter("Id", id))`.

Which is a method on the `ObjectContext`.

But `DbContext` has no such method.

How do we call a stored proc? Is it not supported in EF CTP5?

**EDIT:**

I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/adonetefx/thread/bae30a3d-7a66-4aff-af99-6426cf0483b5), which states you need to do this:

```
  var people = context.People.SqlQuery("EXECUTE [dbo].[GetAllPeople]");
```

This raises some concerns:

1) You are now calling a stored prodedure on the *set*, not the *context*. Stored procedures should be available context-wide, not tied to a particular entity set. Just like how they are under the "Database" in SQL Server, and not under the "Table".

2) What about **complex types**? I previously had a complex type being returned from a stored procedure. But now, it looks as though you have to map directly to an entity? That doesn't make any sense. I have many stored procs that return a type not directly represented by an ObjectSet/DBSet, which i can't see how i can pull over.

Hope someone can clear this up for me, because from what i understand so far, i won't be able to upgrade to CTP5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can execute database-wide sql statements like this

```
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
    // custum sql statement
    var c = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Employees");

    // returned entity type doesn't have to be represented by ObjectSet/DBSet
    var e = context.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("SELECT * FROM Employees");

    // stored procedure
    var q = context.Database.SqlQuery<Employee>("GetEmployees");
}
```

Comment: This answers your first concern. The sp's are available context-wide. DbContext.Database is a reference to the built-in DbDatabase object. This is different from context.People.SqlQuery which operates on the DbSet.

Comment: From my comment: "The sp's are available context-wide.". This should be "Database-wide" since you can query data that isn't related to the context.