# Using stored procedures with Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP5

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework 4 Code First CTP5 and ASP.NET MVC 3.  I would like to know how do I make use of stored procedures?

I have the following code in my respository class:

```
MyDatabaseContext db = new MyDatabaseContext();

public void Insert(News news)
{
   db.Newses.Add(news);
   db.SaveChanges();
}
```

And then my insert store procedure will look like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[News_Insert]
(
   @Title VARCHAR(100),
   @Body VARCHAR(MAX),
   @NewsStatusId INT
)

AS

BEGIN

   INSERT INTO
      News
      (
         Title,
         Body,
         NewsStatusId
      )
      VALUES
      (
         @Title,
         @Body,
         @NewsStatusId
      );

  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

END
```

Any articles/advice would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 1:**

With the designer I could return the new object or news ID, how would I do this here?

**UPDATE 2**

This is what I did:

```
public void Insert(News news)
{
   int newsId = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>("News_Insert @Title, @Body, @Active",
      new SqlParameter("Title", news.Title),
      new SqlParameter("Body", news.Body),
      new SqlParameter("Active", news.Active)
   ).FirstOrDefault();

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I get an error here saying:

**The specified cast from a materialized 'System.Decimal' type to the 'System.Int32' type is not valid.**

My News class:

```
public class News
{
   public int NewsId { get; set; }
   public string Title { get; set; }
   public string Body { get; set; }
   public bool Active { get; set; }
}
```

I am using an existing database and my connection string looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add
      name="MyDatabaseContext"
      connectionString="Data Source=MyServer;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;Integrated Security=True;"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Here is my context class:

```
public class MyDatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<News> Newses { get; set; }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here?  Is my stored procedure maybe incorrect?  Ideally I would like to return the new updated object.  Can someone please advise?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework CTP5 - How to Call Stored Procedure?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789788/entity-framework-ctp5-how-to-call-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no direct mapping support for stored procedures (as known from EDMX). You can simply call your procedure instead of `Add` method by using `db.Database.SqlCommand` method. Try this:

```
db.Database.SqlCommand("dbo.News_Insert @Title, @Body, @NewsStatusId",
  new SqlParameter("Title", news.Title),
  new SqlParameter("Body", news.Body),
  new SqlParameter("NewsStatusId", news.NewStatus.Id));
```

Comment: @Ladislav Mrnka: Thanks. Why do you think they did not add mapping to stored procedures? Is this the only way to do it?  Also, please see my update to my original post.

Comment: @Brendan: I don't know why they didn't add sp mapping - It is question for ADO.NET team. If you need to return something from your sp follow example in question linked by @RPM1984.

Comment: @Ladislav: Please see my update 2. I tried your code and got an error. Please advise :) Not sure what else you need to see?  The stored procedure to add the news item is also in my original post.

Comment: @Brendan: Your stored procedure only inserts data, it doesn't perform any select so it can't return data back to EF.

Comment: @Ladislav: What would the select look like to return the updated object?

Comment: Will my context.Database.SqlQuery have to change as well?  Please provide some decent code samples.

Comment: @Brendan: Why are you using native SQL and stored procedure when you don't know how to use it? Basically you need to execute select only if you have any fields generated in DB. If you have only Id generated in db it should be enough to call SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY(), use SqlQuery<int> and set Id of your stored News instance.

Comment: I changed as what you recommended but I get errors.  I updated the original post, please can you check and advise?

Comment: @Brendan: Try to replace the select statement with SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS INT)

Comment: @Ladislav: It does work now, thanks.  Just a final question, do I still need context.SaveChanges();?

Comment: @Brendan: You don't need to call SaveChanges to execute your SP. But if you added anything else into any DbSet it will not be save until you call SaveChanges.

Comment: Um.. EF does provide support for SPs.  It calls them functional imports.

Comment: @Jordan: Read the question. OP uses code first and code first doesn't have function imports - its a feature of EDMX.

Answer (score 1):

you can write stored procedures in sql and your entity update and then conversion it to function and use it such as function in your program,db-click on the Entity Model and in open page(EntityModel) then i right side page db-click on folder that called StoredproceduresEntity and open then right click on the a `StoredProcedures` and select option `AddFunction...` then select type of output 
go to:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Comment: Code first doesn't have an entity model.