# Saving multiple objects

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository

I have the following classes:

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<TestQuestion> Questions { get; set; }
}

public class TestQuestion
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public List<TestQuestionAnswer> Answers { get; set; }
}

public class TestQuestionAnswer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int TestQuestionId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCorrect { get; set; }
}
```

I'm having some problems with `Save` method in `TestRepository`.

Here's the logic:

```
If Test.Id > 0 then update Test, otherwise create a new one
If TestQuestion.Id > 0 and TestQuestion.Text = "" delete TestQuestion from database and all Answers for that object
If TestQuestion.Id == 0 then create a new row in database
If TestQuestion.Id > 0 and TestQuestion.Text != "" then update that row
If TestQuestionAnswer.Id > 0 and Text = "" then delete it from database, otherwise call create or update method.
```

I'm using Entity Framework Code First, but I'm willing to switch to classic ADO.NET if that would make this job much easier.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why not instead of blanking out items you want to delete just delete the objects you want deleted. Turn cascade deletes on so that when you delete a question all answers automatically get deleted. You're doing a lot of manual work that EF does for you.

Comment: Because that was requested. I have to create a web form, similar to excel sheet. If field is blank, delete it, otherwise create a new row in the database or update an existing one :(

Answer (score 1):

Given the apparent complexity of your update, it would probably make sense to move its logic to a stored procedure, and then [map your updates to that stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001441/using-stored-procedures-with-entity-framework-4-code-first-ctp5).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Stored procedure would be totally ok, but I have very little experience in writing SPs. Could you give me a sample with "complex" object hierarchy Test/TestQuestion/TestQuestionAnswer ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can make this simple and as you said, you would like to switch to classic ADO.NET,

1. Create a Stored Procedure and place all of these logic in there. This can be done in a single Transction.
2. Write the ADO.NET coding with related QUERY's.

I personally prefer first option since that will make use of the existing Entity Framework.

Let me know further direction and also may I know the issues while using Save method in TestRepository.

Comment: I would like to use a Stored Procedure and make CRUD in a single Transaction. Do I have to write 3 CRUD Stored Procedures for each entity, or can I just create one? In that case, I would have to create a new User-Defined Table Type and set is as input parameter in my SP, right?